# Text to Speech in Java using Google

Tags: java, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have used the following code to convert text to speech, but I am getting the following errors:

**errors**

*Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://ipv4.google.com/sorry/IndexRedirect?continue=http://translate.google.com/translate_tts%3Fie%3DUTF-8%26q%3DHello%2BWorld%26tl%3Dde%26prev%3Dinput&q=CGMSBCmIeyUYvpnkrwUiGQDxp4NLHAGq2VYVjoplnZ0vwMrZvShTrYA
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at us.monoid.web.AbstractResource.fill(AbstractResource.java:30)
    ... 5 more*

**Java Codes**

```
public class TextToSpeech {

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q={0}&tl={1}&prev=input";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    say("Hello World");
}

public static void say(String text) {
    try {
        File f = new File("translate.mp3");
        String sentence = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
        String urlString = MessageFormat.format(BASE_URL, sentence, "de");
        BinaryResource res = new Resty().bytes(new URI(urlString));
        res.save(f);

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

        Player p = new Player(in);

        p.play();

        p.close();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note that I have already included the jar files JLayer & Resty.. Please help ! Thanks

Comment: Seems like the server is temporarily unavailable. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492370/server-returned-http-response-code-503-for-url

Comment: @BalwinderSingh Is there any alternatives ?

Comment: you cannot use directly the url like this - you need to create a developper account and have credentials to use the service, see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2

Comment: @FredericHenri meaning the service is no more publicly available ? 
Is there any alternatives to this ?

Comment: the service is available but you need to authenticate yourself, see the link I provide you. If you have google account it should be sufficient

Comment: Yes, I have already login with my google account.. 
What is the next step to do ?
Any changes in my code ?

Comment: Where do you do that in your code ? you're not passing any credentials. you should definitely read through the guide from google. There's too much to post to make a single answer

Comment: Can you just please advise me where should I pass the credentials ?